# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dist' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, supervised-learning, pomegranate

I am trying to train a model for supervised learning for Hidden Markov Model (HMM)and test it on a set of observations however, keep getting this error. The goal is to predict the state based on the observations. How can I fix this and how can I view the transition matrix?

The version for Pomegranate is 0.14.4
Trying this from the source: https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/issues/1005

```
from pomegranate import *
import numpy as np
# Supervised method that calculates the transition matrix:
d1 = State(UniformDistribution.from_samples([3.243221498397177, 3.210684537495482, 3.227662201472816,
    3.286410817416738, 3.290573650708864, 3.286058136226862, 3.266480693857006]))
d2 = State(UniformDistribution.from_samples([3.449282367485096, 1.97317859465635, 1.897551432353011,
     3.454609351559659, 3.127357456033111, 1.779308337786426, 3.802891929694426, 3.359766157565077, 2.959428499979418]))
d3 = State(UniformDistribution.from_samples([1.892812118441474, 1.589353118681066, 2.09269978285637,
     2.104391496570218, 1.656771181054144]))
model = HiddenMarkovModel()
model.add_states(d1, d2, d3)
# print(model.to_json())
model.bake()
model.fit([3.2, 6.7, 10.55], labels=[1, 2, 3], algorithm='labeled')
all_pred = model.predict([2.33, 1.22, 1.4, 10.6])
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/", line 774, in <module>
    model.bake()
  File "pomegranate/hmm.pyx", line 1047, in pomegranate.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel.bake
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dist' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: That's a bug in the `pomegranate` library. Talk to its authors, not to us.

Comment: ...that said, if I _were_ to run this down inside `pomegranate`, I'd want to know exactly which version of the library you're running so I'm not wasting my time looking at the wrong source. It can't be the latest one -- [in the tip of the main branch, line 1047 is a comment](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/f115a242a5b50854bbf199d43fe2cfd061e9708a/pomegranate/hmm.pyx#L1047).

Comment: (...that said, from a cursory glance at the source, and making some assumptions about which version you're running, it _looks_ like you could get this bug by having only silent states -- that is to say, states with `distribution=None`. Still, it's a pomegranate problem that they don't raise a useful/meaningful exception in that case)

Comment: The version for Pomegranate is 0.14.4

Comment: Duplicate of this issue on the source repo: https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/issues/1005 Actually, the code there is identical to the code here. @maximus, are you smalik89 on GitHub? If so, it would be helpful to spell that out explicitly in the question, and if not, please quote your sources.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in promegranate.

This Python `UnboundLocalError: Local variable referenced before assignment`" occurs when we reference a local variable before assigning a value to it in a function.

Observing the [hmm.pyx code](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/master/pomegranate/hmm.pyx), dist is assigned a value in a function's body(which is a local variable) and not declared as global.
To solve the error, mark the variable as global in the function definition,

```
e.g. global dist
```

Try adding `dist` variable in your code that you provided.
For e.g.
Hope this helps!